# Is it ok for the period to go after/outside the quotation mark?

Tags: quotation-marks, periods

I typically end sentences with the phrase:

> ...annexed hereto is Exhibit "A".

In such a case is grammatically acceptable that the period is outside the ending quotation mark? Inside the ending quotation mark just doesn't look right.

Comment: Using quotation marks does not make a "quote". Yes, the AE style is to ignore context and hold the period inside, but it has to be a quotation. Why can't you call it Exhibit A? Annexed hereto is? Mabye all you need is "For more details, see Exhibit A."

Comment: Related ELL question: [Do periods and question marks come inside the quotation mark, or outside?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79845/do-periods-and-question-marks-come-inside-the-quotation-mark-or-outside) It's a different stack so can't VTC.